# How change IIS Express runtime from 4.0 to 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-express, sharpdevelop

I'm trying to run using SharpDevelop a MVC2 web app. When I try to run the application, the following error show up in the browser:

> Config Error     There is a duplicate
>   'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section
>   defined
>
> and ...
>
> If you see the text "There is a duplicate
>   'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section
>   defined", this error is because you are running a .NET Framework
>   3.5-based application in .NET Framework 4. If you are running WebMatrix, to resolve this problem, go to the Settings node to set the
>   .NET Framework version to ".NET 2". You can also remove the extra
>   sections from the web.config file.

I'm on Windows 7 and have installed WebMatrix but can't figure out how to do what the error message tell me:

> set the .NET Framework version to ".NET 2"

How can I change that config to avoid the error?

Comment: You don't want to change the Framework version of IIS. You want to change the framework version of the App Pool you're running in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the command:

```
appcmd set app /app.name:APPLICATION_NAME/ /applicationPool:Clr2IntegratedAppPool
```

More info about the command [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)

Remember change to the right(you could have more than one IIS installed) IIS directory before execute the command,

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express
```

in my case.